# How to hide tokenURI values from other people

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I am looking for a way to hide the tokenURI values from other people as they can call the tokenURI contract from etherscan and by editing the URL of it, they can snipe the rarest NFT's in my project and this is an unwanted situation.

https://etherscan.io/address/0xF407B994F05d2b2cA66534517a9C85a117Db54A5
For example, in this contract, you can call the tokenURI of a minted token and it returns the link of their api, which is https://ploddingpirateapi.herokuapp.com/api/token/962 and people just can edit the "962" section in the link and could see the unminted NFT's and just wait for his turn to buy this.

Any way of preventing this situation is fine by me. If I don't verify the contract in etherscan, they won't be able to see it but also I won't be able to withdraw the contract's balance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything on Ethereum is public. The only way to hide this information is to publish this in ciphertext instead of plaintext.